# Copy to clipboard slow in VS 2022 with Windows Defender

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, windows-defender

In the last 2 weeks all of our developers are complaining about Visual Studio 2022 IDE that behaves slower than before.
So far we traced it back to Windows Defender, we have multiple modules enabled from IT. With Defender compleltly disabled, the issue is gone.

When a user selects a piece of text, no matter how much, and process Ctrl+C, or right click and choose Copy, the app will hang for a second or 2.
We can make the problem worst by selecting text and pressing Ctrl+C multiple times. It seems to stack the delays and do all the copies behind each other.
[image]

That dialog leads me to believe that Visual Studio has a special copy task running in the background.
Other VS actions also became slower, but this is an easy example.
During the delay, we see the Antimalware Service Executable spike up.
[image]

While working with our IT department to find how to finetune Windows Defender, i hope anyone here can point us in the right direction.
I searched online, but could not find anythign on a Visual Studio background task doing the copy.

Comment: Has anyone been able to resolve this issue?

Comment: The issue has bene resolved by us by adding devenv.exe to the exclusion list. Not ideal but no other fix has been found yet.